# overriding a function within the jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms, plugins

I am using the [jquery form validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate a long form. If a user submits the form with multiple fields that fail to validate, the cursor returns to the last field that did not pass. Instead, I want the cursor to be returned to the first field in the form that failed validation. Rather than modifying the plugin, I would like to override focusInvalid, which is nested inside "prototype: {...}":

```
focusInvalid: function() {
    if( this.settings.focusInvalid ) {
        try {
            $(this.findLastActive() || this.errorList.length && this.errorList[0].element || []).filter(":visible").focus();
        } catch(e) {
            // ignore IE throwing errors when focusing hidden elements
        }
    }
},
```

I've tried adding my own version of focusInvalid within the following, but I haven't been able to get that to work:

```
$("form#user-register").validate({. . .});
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the selection of the first invalid input with the `focusInvalid` option. You can then use the `invalidHandler` option to set a custom function that selects the first element in your form. The `invalidHandler` option is the function that the plugin calls when an invalid form is submitted.

Example below:

```
$("form#user-register").validate({
     invalidHandler: function(form, validator){
         $(validator.invalidElements()[0]).focus();
     },
     focusInvalid:false
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about invalidHandler. The code above is close to what I need; however, I'd like the user to be returned to the first *invalid* field.

I thought it would be something along the lines of:
<pre><code>
    invalidHandler: function(){
      $(this.errorList[0].element).filter(":visible").focus();
    },
    focusInvalid: false
</pre></code>

. . . but I haven't been able to get that to work. Any further points?

Thanks!

Comment: Updated. You were on the right track with what you were doing. You can still filter use the `:visible` filter if you want but it would only be needed if you are validating hidden inputs.