# jquery validation plug-in and scrolling

Tags: jquery, validation, scroll

I'm using the jquery validation plug-in. When there are invalid fields, it focuses on the first invalid field. However, my labels are on top of my fields and I want to scroll up just a bit so the user can see both the label and the field. I've looked at the scrollTo plug-in, but haven't figured out an easy way to integrate it. Maybe someone has done something like this before?

Comment: can you maybe show us how you do the scrolling up till now?
you say it scrolls towards the inputfield, so there is already some scrolling in place.

Comment: @sander setting the focus to something off-screen will force the browser to scroll at least far enough that the focused element is seen.  that may be browser implementation dependent, though

Comment: I'm using the jquery validate plugin. Indeed it focuses to the first invalid element. If that element if off-screen, it does indeed scroll just up to that element (input field), but not any higher. It doesn't scroll, it just jumps very quickly to the field. If there is a scroll, it's too fast to be perceived.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I'm displaying my validation error's into an ordered list above my form rather than displaying them inline. When the jQuery validate plugin finds an error, I set the form to scroll to the top of the form to notify the user of that error(s) by editing the **invalidHandler** function and disabling the focusInvalid option.

```
$("#residential-evaluation").validate({
 // Scroll to top of #errors on validate
 invalidHandler: function(form, validator){
  $.scrollTo('#errors', "slow");
 },
 focusInvalid:false,
 //Error output
 errorLabelContainer: "#errors",
 wrapper: "li"
});
```

This post was really useful as well:

[overriding a function within the jquery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218118/overriding-a-function-within-the-jquery-validation-plugin)

**This setup relies on the scrollTo plugin for that added animation.**

Comment: If you're having issues with IE and scrollTo you could try using **window.location.hash="errors";**

Comment: The scrollTo setup was just tested in IE8 and 7 and seems to work fine, animation included.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you used the focus to jump to your element which failed validation.

you can remove that code since you are going to try implement scrolling towards that element.

these steps need to be taken in order to scroll to the correct element.

1. adding the scrollTo plugin inside your head.
2. making sure that the label is ready (with an ID or class or something) (which in your case is the target, since you want to scroll to the location of the label and not the input field)
3. if you now do:

   $.scrollTo( '#yourlabelID', "slow");

it will roll to the position of your label.

as in regular scrolling, if the element is too close to the bottom of the page, it will only scroll to the bottom of the page and not further.

demo: http://sander.netcentric.be/test/scroll.html

Comment: I implemented this. In the jquery-validate.js, right before it puts focus on the first invalid element, I put the scrollTo to the label fo that element. It works great in Firefox, but not in IE. I think it's a problem with scrollTo and IE.

Comment: the example i created seems to work both in IE and firefox on my computer, so there must be something with the validateplugin and scrollTo combination i suppose.